# Way to inject function into chain with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, chaining

I'm looking for a way to take the contents of the underscore chain and pass it into a function, in this case the chain parses out the timestamp from the file and sorts the array by timestamp, gets the latest one then I'd like to simply reassemble the path with `path.format`. Is there a way to do this with underscore that I'm simply overlooking?

```
  return _.chain(dirFiles)
    .filter(function(dirFile){
      return dirFile.match(file.name)
    })
    .map(function(dirFile){
      dirFile = path.parse(dirFile)
      dirFile.timestamp = dirFile.name.split("-")[file.timestampPosition]
      return dirFile
    })
    .sortBy("timestamp")
    .last()
    .inject(path.format)
    .value()
```

Comment: You mean like `.map(path.format).last()`?

Comment: @Bergi I could use map but it would have to come before last.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: is there a problem with that?

Comment: Hmm, so you are looking for a `map` version of a single object (which probably also just a primitive value)?

Comment: I was just looking for a more generic solution that would work in any case. @Bergi map works.

Comment: The closest one would be `mapObject`. But as you may already have had a look at, it has a limited functionality - only map key-value pair of an object with a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. However, lodash does provide a [`_.thru`](https://lodash.com/docs#thru) method since v3:

> ```
> _.thru(value, interceptor, [thisArg])
> ```
>
> This method is like `_.tap` except that it returns the result of interceptor.

You surely can [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) it into underscore :-)

Answer (score 0):

**_.mixin**

Underscore has an option for you to create your own mapping function which maps an object or any kind of data to another object or any kind of data in your own way.

**All you need is a definition of your own function**

Below is just an example of how to define your function with `mixin`

```
_.mixin({
    pathFormat: function(val,interceptor){ 
       // Just an example of how you can pass in your own interceptor
       return interceptor(val) + path.resolve(val); 
    }
});
```

Then pluck your own function in the chain like this:

```
_.chain(dirFiles)
   ...
   ...
   sortBy("timestamp")
   .last()
   .pathFormat(path.format)
   .value()
```

With this, `pah.format` is an interceptor function you pass in to the `pathFormat` function you have defined. So you can process an object returned by `last()` and map it to another resultant object, returns it back to the subsequent chaining function.